# Dúvida com expressão regular, dados de uma url

Tags: php, javascript, regex

Tenho estas URLs

> ```
> veiculos-sao-paulo-__4--6--.html
> veiculos-parana__4--6--.html
> veiculos-rio-de-janeiro-__4--6--.html
> ```

Com esta expressão regular:

```
^veiculos-([a-zA-Z-]+)__.+\.html?
```

Pego o *grupo $1* com as seguintes saídas:

> sao-paulo-
>
> parana
>
> rio-de-janeiro-

Gostaria de não receber o hífen "-" do final.

Como eu poderia adaptara minha *regex* para não capturar o hífen, considerando que ele pode ou não vir no final da url?

saída pretendida:

> sao-paulo
>
> parana
>
> rio-de-janeiro

Comment: Com exatamente a mesma regex, mas coloque o hífen após o grupo que você deseja capturar: `^veiculos-([a-zA-Z-]+)-__.+\.html?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expressão regular: `.*?-(.+?)-?_.*`

Teste: https://regex101.com/r/frWvgd/1

Comment: Obrigado Pedro.
Perfeito